# Azure AppInsights - Http Result code Faulted

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, load-testing, azure-application-insights, azure-api-management

We have configured APIM, WebApp in Azure and then connected AppInsights Log to get the details in case of failure.

We are doing load testing on APIM.

At one point, we started getting 500 error code which means that there is issue at application level.

When we looked in details, at one point, we got http result code as "Faulted" & we do not get any errors underneath API, servers.

So I would like to know what means by "Faulted"?

[image: A]

Comment: Judging by the duration, it looks like the GET request timed out after around 20 seconds. Common culprits here are thread starvation or poor application performance. If it's threads, suggest looking at async / await or equivalent in your language of implementation, on all I/O bound activity.

Comment: Thanks Stuart for your quick reply. We start getting this error in 5-10 seconds, so timeout might not be the issue, and underneath servers CPU usage does not go > 25%

Comment: Thread starvation due to I/O bound work usually won't show as high CPU usage, unless there's a lot of context switching going on due to a high threadpool count.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an explanation from the `ApplicationInsights-dotnet` repo issues on [HttpCoreDiagnosticListener tracks exceptions](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1362#issuecomment-511488536)

> This issue is about DependencyCollection module tracking an Exception event along with a DependencyTelemetry in the event of client side errors like DNS. The exception is sent to user ikey, along with DependencyTelemetry.
>
> If this exception is not tracked, then the only information DependencyCollector has is that call failed, and resultCode as "Faulted". We should modify the result code to be more useful, before removing the actual exception.
>
> Btw, DependencyCollection for .NET Framework does not track this exception, so making netcore also behave same is good for consistency point.