# How should the 'Failed' result code of the request be interpreted? What does it exactly mean?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

In the `failures` tab of Azure Application Insights, I'm sporadically seeing requests to the other microservice whose `result code` is marked as `faulted`.

[image]

How can I diagnose this problem? What does the "Faulted" result code in AppInsights mean? Is this a bug in my code? Network error? Problem with AI itself?

I can't find this request in the AI in `requests' table for this target microservice, so I assume it hasn't arrived at its destination.

Comment: What is the  framework of your Application?How you have configured Application Insights in your App ?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: If your request has any exception and it is not handled by the application, then the result code is shown as `Faulted`

Comment: @Harshitha but is this a problem with app sending request or the one receiving it? Shouln't my miroservice return http 500 when unhandled exception occurs?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @Piotrek, according to screenshot - these are outgoing requests. If a request receives a response code (let's say, 500) then it is visualized as is. In this case, either it is client side error and it is replaced with Faulted. Or this telemetry is produced by a component which deliberately put "Faulted" there.

Comment: @Piotrek, re: 500. If your request handles these failures (or ignores them; for instance, they are produced by another library which retries and as a result an operation succeeds) then it still can return OK.

Comment: This seems to be a network error.As it does not have any more details, failed to log in AI.

Comment: Refer Similar issue explained in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60540667/azure-appinsights-http-result-code-faulted)